# Windsor and DbContext per request - DbContext has been disposed

Tags: entity-framework, castle-windsor, dbcontext

I have a method in HomeController, that I'm trying to access through URL, like this:

```
http://localhost/web/home/GetSmth
```

First time it works, but after refreshing page, I get this error:

```
The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.
```

As the title states, I'm trying to use Castle Windsor and DbContext per request.

```
       public class Installer1 : IWindsorInstaller
            {
                public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
                {
                    container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                                    .BasedOn<IController>()
                                    .LifestyleTransient()                            
                                    );

                    var connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainDbContext"].ConnectionString;

                    container.Register(Component.For<MainDbContext>().DependsOn(Property.ForKey("conn").Eq(connString)).LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);
                    container.Register(Component.For<ISomeService>().ImplementedBy<SomeService>());
                }
}
```

HomeController looks like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
        private ISomeService _someService;

        public HomeController(ISomeService someService)
        {
            _someService = someService;            
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {     
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult GetSmth()
        {
            var data = _someService.GetData().ToList();
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are registering `ISomeService` with the default lifecycle, which is singleton. Once it's created, it will keep using the same DbContext. Simplest solution is to change its lifecycle to per request or transient.

```
container.Register(Component.For<ISomeService>()
                            .ImplementedBy<SomeService>()
                            .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);
```

Comment: So that means, that all classes that use DbContext (Services, Repositories, QueryObjects, etc) should use this lifetime?

Comment: @andree That's true. Castle Windsor even warns you about it, check it on debugger.